# What happen if kmem_cache has no free memory for allocating?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I create a slab cache by `kmem_cache_create(... size)`, then allocate memory from this cache by `kmem_cache_alloc()`.

After I have allocated memory for "size" times, what happen if I call `kmem_cache_alloc()` to allocat `size + 1`th memory? Return NULL or extend cache implicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'size' argument is not about memory reserved for anything. It is about the size of each allocation as returned by kmem_cache_alloc.

It may be there will be memory shortage in general, in which case, depending on flags pased to kmem_cache_alloc, the kernel may try to free some by e.g. shrinking caches.